# How to resolve 'scanLocation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0?

Tags: deprecated, ios13

When trying to use a Scanner I am getting the warning that 'scanLocation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0.Apple's documentation for Scanner does not even mention the deprecation, let alone suggest what has taken the place of scanLocation.

Example of using scanLocation, which is deprecated:

```
convenience init(hexString: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0   // 'scanLocation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0
        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `currentIndex` instead of `scanLocation`

```
scanner.currentIndex = hexString.startIndex
```